# NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

```
print ('There are',232//60) ('hours and',232%60) ('minutes in 232 minutes')
```

I tried so many things and although it's my teacher answer it doesn't let me

Comment: If this is your teacher's answer then you need a different teacher. These parentheses are nonsensical

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The syntax is `print(thing1, thing2, ...)`, with `thing1`,`thing2`, etc replaced by the things you want printed.

Comment: print ('There are',232//60) ('hours and',232%60) ('minutes in 232 minutes')
not working and shows me on the screen: ypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable again

Comment: I think we understand the question, but what are you expecting it to actually print? If you look at the Python documentation for the print method, there is never multiple sets of parenthesis

Comment: I need to print a Python code that calculates how many hours and minutes are there in 232 minutes, and outputs the result with the use of '%' and '//'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your teachers actual suggestion:

```
print( 'There are',232//60 , ' hours and ', 232%60 , 'minutes in', 232, 'minutes')
```

IMHO, a better way (works in 3.6 and later):

```
print( f'There are {232//60} hours and {232%60} minutes in {232} minutes')
```

Better yet is to have the minutes as a variable:

```
minutes = 232
print( f'There are {minutes//60} hours and {minutes%60} minutes in {minutes} minutes')
```